# How to place one image on top of another, and update?

Tags: python, image, pysimplegui

I don't know where to start:

```
from PIL import Image


im1 = Image.open('C:/background.png') # size = 1065x460px
```

I need to load an image that would be the "background", and on this image I will place a series of circles when a condition is met.
And when another condition is met, delete or update only the previous circle (the background must always remain) and place the new circle

**I just edited the post:**

Now I have an image that will be the background (that I will never erase)
and on the other hand I have the circles, which will be generated by graph.DrawCircle and my question, is there a way to update and delete these circles, that is, when I place the 2nd circle the 1st is deleted.

```
layout = [sg.Graph(canvas_size=(1065, 460), graph_bottom_left=(0, 0), 
graph_top_right=(1065, 460), key="-GRAPH-")]

graph = window.Element("-GRAPH-")
def circle_position(x,y,r):
    graph.DrawCircle((x,y), r, line_color='red')
```

before drawing a circle I have to erase all circles (but not the background) :

```
    elif (event =="Display Error Code") or (event == 'Submit'):

        # erasing all the circles------before drawing the new circle

        circle_position(324,257,16)

    if (values[0] == "1002") :  # 2nd circle

         # erasing all the circles------before drawing the new circle

        circle_position(342,303,16)
```

Thanks again

Comment: Most dynamic displays are constantly redrawing the screen, and those that have foreground and background objects, the redraw loop will typically draw the background first, (possibly clearing the screen at the beginning), then draw over that background the objects in the foreground, the last one showing up "on top" of the others.

Comment: Using element `sg.Graph` to create a canvas, then you can draw images on it by method `draw_image(filename=None, data=None, location=(None, None))` which will return a id to represent the item you drawn on canvas, then you can delete it by method `delete_figure(id)` any time.